# Apache beam : Programatically create partitioned tables

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing a cloud dataflow that reads messages from Pubsub and stores those into BigQuery. I want to use partitioned table (by date) and I am using `Timestamp` associated with message to determine which partition the message should go into. Below is my code:

```
      BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
        .to(new SerializableFunction<ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow>, TableDestination>() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
              public TableDestination apply(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> value) {
                log.info("Row value : {}", value.getValue());
                Instant timestamp = value.getTimestamp();
                String partition = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").print(timestamp);
                TableDestination td = new TableDestination(
                    "<project>:<dataset>.<table>" + "$" + partition, null);
                log.info("Table Destination : {}", td);
                return td;
              }
          })            
    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)         
    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND) 
    .withSchema(tableSchema);
```

When I deploy the dataflow, I can see the log statements in Stackdriver, however, the messages do not get inserted into BigQuery tables and I get the following error:

```
Request failed with code 400, will NOT retry: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/<project_id>/datasets/<dataset_id>/tables
severity:  "WARNING"
```

So, it looks like it is not able to create a table, resulting in insert failure. Do I need to change the dataflow definition in order to make this work? If not, is there any other way to create the partitioned tables programmatically?

I am using Apache beam 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [a bug in BigQueryIO](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2870) and it has been fixed in Beam 2.2. You can use a snapshot version of Beam, or wait until release 2.2 is finalized (the release process is currently in progress).

Comment: thanks for the update. A couple of follow up questions (sorry): 1. Is there any other way to create tables in dataflow pipeline (than by using apache beam) and 2. When are we expecting beam 2.2 to get released?

Comment: You can create tables by using the BigQuery API directly https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries . Beam release is an Apache community process so there can be no hard guarantees, but it seems likely to happen in the next week or two I think. You can follow the thread https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/3f8dad0a8c4f19e8cabc3255136cbed66251d73060fad76c852daafb@%3Cdev.beam.apache.org%3E

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @jkff.

Comment: Upgraded the library to 2.2.0. Now we are getting the following error with the same code : `Cannot read partition information from a table that is not partitioned:`. So, it looks like it's creating table without partition?

Comment: Could you share the complete stack trace of the error and the dataflow job id?